# how do i make an array of arrays using for loops to input elements to the array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, append, arrayofarrays

```
grades=[]
ClassGrade=[]

NumStudents=int(input(" How Many Students Do You Have ? "))

for i in range(0,2,1):
    prompt=("Input student "+str(i)+"'s grades ")
    for i in range(0,2,1):
        grade=float(input(prompt))
        grades.append(grade)
    ClassGrade.append(grades)


print(ClassGrade)
```

when start inputting the elements for example student 1 : [56,80] and student 2:[90,66]

and i append grades to classGrade when i print out classGrade i get [[56,80,90,66],[56,80,90,66]]

when i'm actually expecting classGrade to be [[56,80],[90,66]]

Comment: you put the *same list* inside the other list *twice*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the array inside the for loop, or you will add all the grades to the same list:

you need to move `grades=[]` from here:

```
grades=[] <---
ClassGrade=[]
```

to:

```
for i in range(0,2,1):
    grades=[] <---
    prompt=("Input student "+str(i)+"'s grades ")
```